# Does AND work in Excel spreadsheet formulae using Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel (2010) cell with this formula:

```
{=SUM(IF('Tasks'!$I:$I=$C4,'Tasks'!$F$2:$F$2000,0))}
```

which works (the correct total is given). But when I enter another item to search for:

```
{=SUM(IF(AND('Tasks'!$H:$H=B4,'Tasks'!$I:$I=$C4),'Tasks'!$F$2:$F$2000,0))}
```

it does not work (total is zero). Does `AND` not work in this case? Or have I made an error?

*Explanation of code: I have two sheets, a **Total** sheet (where this code is placed) and a **Tasks** sheet. The Tasks sheet contains work priority (in H column), people (in I column) and estimated time (in F column). So I want to find out, per person and per tasks priority, how much work is estimated. The first line of code is just estimated time per person which, as I wrote, works fine. On the Total sheet, B4 contains the priority of the current item and C4 the name of the current person.*

Comment: I posted an answer but note that if you are using that first formula exactly as shown then you will probably get incorrect results because of the mismatched ranges - that formula will add the value from the `next row` when the condition is satisfied, e.g. if I99 = C4 then F100 is added to the sum.....I assume you don't want it to work like that....

Comment: @barryhoudini: correct, I was going to change my question to use `$F:$F` but then I saw that it confuse people reading your answer (containing `F2:F2000`). Is that where the VTC comes from?

Comment: VTC? Not sure what that means....

Comment: @barryhoudini: sorry, vote to close.

Comment: OK I see - I believe that pure formula based questions should really be at SuperUser - some of these type of questions get moved there......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, No, `AND` doesn't do what you need here because it returns a single result (only TRUE if all conditions for all cells are TRUE) rather than an "array" of TRUE/FALSE values for each cell in the range.

You need to use * (to multiply and simulate AND) or use multiple IFs

Also you should keep the ranges the same size, in which case you can use this "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(('Tasks'!$H$2:$H$2000=B4)*('Tasks'!$I$2:$I$2000=$C4),'Tasks'!$F$2:$F$2000))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

....but in Excel 2010 SUMIFS would be preferable (with sum range at the start), i.e.

`=SUMIFS('Tasks'!F:F,'Tasks'!H:H,B4,'Tasks'!I:I,C4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested IF like so:

```
{=SUM(IF('Tasks'!$H:$H=B4, if('Tasks'!$I:$I=$C4, 'Tasks'!$F$2:$F$2000,0), 0))}
```